# Java MongoDB 3.6 Aggregation with Cursor option

Tags: java, mongodb

This is the aggregation I'd like to run, using Java mongodb driver.

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {            
           _id: {  status: "$status" },
           totalAmount: { $sum: "$filesize" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Command works fine running in the Shell, against Mongo 3.6.

When trying to run in Java:

> "errmsg" : "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with
>   the explain argument"

I can't work out from the Java docs how to specify the 'cursor' option, or  any of the options specified in the docs:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate

In Java, the aggregate command will only take the following parameters:

collection.aggregate(pipeline, aggregationOptions));

- pipline: List
- aggregationOptions: options to apply to the
  aggregation...

Aggration Options:
 - outputMode
 - allowDiskUse
 - batchSize
 - maxTime

Comment: Noting usage of `DBObject` here which has been removed from the standard for many years now. Despite your claimed driver version in the title, you appear to be using an older and unsupported driver. All [current releases](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) all return a "cursor" by default. To return a `List` in modern releases is actually done via explicit options instead of the other way around as you are claiming here. The older linked question and answer should give an indication as to how long ago this was the new default.

Comment: You are correct, the server version was 3.6, but the code was being migrated and was using an older driver, which probably accounts for the confusion!

Answer (score 4):

Writing this question I worked out the following solution:

You HAVE to set **outputMode** to **CURSOR**, like this:

```
AggregationOptions aggregationOptions = AggregationOptions.builder().outputMode(AggregationOptions.OutputMode.CURSOR).build();

Iterator<DBObject> cursor = getCollection().aggregate(pipeline, aggregationOptions);
```

There are only two options to outputMode:

- CURSOR
- INLINE.

Inline returns an error...

This interface is quite confusing when trying to work between the Shell and Java.

It would seem to make sense to allow the *options* to be a DBObject document. Alternatively have a constructor for AggregationOptions that takes a DBObject.